# Saving the screen on a ZX Spectrum without the prompt

Tags: zx-spectrum, screen

Saving the [screen](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/212/what-format-is-the-timex-sinclair-zx-spectrum-screen-scr-file/217#217) on a Spectrum will typically get part of it obscured with the message “**Start tape, then press any key.**”:
[image: Screen with annoying tape prompt]
How might one save the screen image from Sinclair BASIC *without* it being corrupted in this way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One simple answer is to copy the screen to a buffer elsewhere in memory and save it from there.

```
10 CLEAR 58455
... generate the screen image here ...
900 FOR n=0 TO 6911
910 POKE 58456+n, PEEK (16384+n)
920 NEXT n
930 SAVE "image" CODE 58456,6912
```

It's also possible to disable the prompt immediately before the SAVE, by changing the input / output functions for the "K" device:

```
900 POKE 23734,111: REM suppress prompt
910 POKE 23736,20: REM don't wait for keypress
920 SAVE "image" SCREEN$
```

Comment: Yup, the (slow) BASIC loop works, as also found in an old [Sinclair User Helpline](http://www.sinclairuser.com/032/helplne.htm "... with Andrew Hewson"). Couldn't get the prompt suppression to work, though maybe I made a typo.